# How to filter date numbers, incomplete dates, and NAs from database and convert to uniform date class in r

Tags: r, date, dplyr

I have a large database with a date column that has date numbers coming from Excel, incomplete dates that are missing the year (but year is in another column), and some cells with missing date. I found out how to change format of the dates, but the problem is how to filter the three types of cells I have in the `date` variable (that is date numbers from excel, incomplete dates, and empty cell). I managed to do it by filtering a by a created column (`value`) that I DON'T have in the real database.

This is my original database:

[image]

This is what I required end result:

[image]

What I managed to do was to filter the dataset with the fictitious `value` column and convert the `date` to the required format. This is what I did:

```
library(dplyr)

data_a <- read.csv(text = "
year,date,value
2018,43238,1
2017,43267,2
2020,7/25,3
2018,,4
2013,,5
2000,8/23,6
2000,9/21,7")

data_b <- data_a %>% 
  filter(value %in% c(1,2)) %>%
  mutate(data_formatted = as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = "1899-12-30"))

data_c <- data_a %>%
  filter(value %in% c(3, 6, 7)) %>%
  mutate(data_formatted = as.Date(paste0(year, "/", date)))

data_d <- data_a %>% 
  filter(value %in% c(4, 5)) %>%
  mutate(data_formatted = NA)

data_final <- rbind(data_b, data_c, data_d)
```

I need to do the same all at once WITHOUT using the `value` column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use do conditional for the scenarios and apply different functions to convert to date.

### Code

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(lubridate)

data_a %>% 
  mutate(
    data_formatted = case_when(
      !str_detect(date,"/") ~ as.Date(as.numeric(date), origin = "1899-12-30"),
      TRUE ~ ymd(paste0(year, "/", date))
    ) 
  )
```

### Output

```
  year  date value data_formatted
1 2018 43238     1     2018-05-18
2 2017 43267     2     2018-06-16
3 2020  7/25     3     2020-07-25
4 2018           4           <NA>
5 2013           5           <NA>
6 2000  8/23     6     2000-08-23
7 2000  9/21     7     2000-09-21
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```r
data_a2 <- data_a %>% mutate(date2=as.numeric(ifelse(str_detect(date,'\\/'), '',date)), 
           date2_=as.numeric(as.Date(ifelse(str_detect(date,'\\/'), paste0(year,'/',date),''), format='%Y/%m/%d')),
           date_formatted=as.Date(coalesce(date2,date2_), origin = "1970-01-01")) %>% 
           dplyr::select(-date2,-date2_)
```